# UIApplication.statusBarStyle changes between viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, statusbar

Running an app in iOS7 initially designed for previous versions, a dark grey navigation bar tints the status bar whose text is black.

I'm trying to adapt it to the newest version, and I'm setting the UIApplication.statusBarStyle to UIStatusBarStyleLightContent like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];
```

This piece of code should change the status bar text colour to white but it doesn't. I put a watchpoint in the _statusBarRequestedStyle property of my UIApplication instance and I could see that this is set to 0 (UIStatusBarStyleDefault) by some call from UIApplicationMain between the execution of viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear methods.

I can't figure out what/why the status bar style is changed at this point and I would appreciate any advice if you have experienced the same.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
From iOS 7 UI Transition Guide (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/Bars.html)

> In iOS 7, you can control the style of the status bar from an individual view controller and change it while the app runs. If you prefer to opt out of this behavior and set the status bar style by using the UIApplication statusBarStyle method, add the UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance key to an app’s Info.plist file and give it the value NO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what happens is the system is updating the status bar according to the view controller status bar appearance. This is new behavior to iOS7, and is on by default.

If you want to use the previous API for status bar appearance, you should set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `NO` in your app's info.plist.

Answer (score 8):

**Option 1:**

1) if your app is View controller-based then you have to set it app.plist file like this:

```
 UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance=NO;
```

[image]

2) you have to set this method in each controller:

```
 -(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
  {
      return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
  }
```

**Option 2:**

Write this single line in **AppDelegate.m** file in **application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];
```

May be it will help.

Comment: The status bar of this app is not View controller-based and Leo's answer fixed my problem. But this makes a lot of sense if the app has to be View controller-based. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will help you 
       Please Try it in your .m file

```
    - (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)
       navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)
       viewController animated:(BOOL)animated

       {
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

      }
```