# Debugging iPhone app on iPad Mini

Tags: ios, iphone, debugging, statusbar

I'm creating an app for iPhone, and i need the statusbar to be hidden.
Nothing worked i thought... I used all the tips i found, until i found out that my iPad Mini, (that i'm using as a testing device), is the only device who still shows the statusbar. (Clock, battery, etc..). The simulator doesn't show it anymore, and the iPad Retina from a friend also doesn't show it.

Is there anyone who knows how I can solve this problem? It's quite frustrating debugging with a sloppy design.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067899/how-to-hide-the-status-bar-in-programmatically-in-ios-7

Comment: if you want to hide your ststus bar only ..for that there are only 3 step and your bar will hide........  Go to your .plist file and add there UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance=NO;.. and click on project there check StatusBar Hide During Launch

Comment: This are all the hints I allready did... I really think it has something to do with the iPad mini.. :s

Comment: follow this Link---- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999625/uiapplication-statusbarstyle-changes-between-viewwillappear-and-viewdidappear/19999872#19999872

Comment: Your application is Universal ?????

Comment: Allready did that Parvendra.. :s

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452638/status-bar-visible-on-ipad-mini-despite-setting-uiviewcontrollerbasedstatusbarap

Comment: It will be, but for now, i'm only making the iPhone part. And thats the one i want to test on my iPad.

Comment: oks For it click on project and make it for iPhone only and then check the box statusbar hide during launching.

Comment: what version of ios are you using in your ipad mini? is the simulator running the same version of ios? @user3484771

Comment: I'm using 7.1 @odukku :)

Comment: @ParvendraSingh, does'nt work either :s

Comment: Its a IOS-bug. [Status bar visible on iPad mini despite setting UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to NO]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452638/status-bar-visible-on-ipad-mini-despite-setting-uiviewcontrollerbasedstatusbarap?lq=1